# Unexplained mono application crash when accessing file list

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, gtk#

I'm trying to get list of files in selected folder with monodevelop on ubuntu 14.10.
When i execute FileChoserButton event, my application crashes without any message on second line (var files =...)

I come from windows forms world and have almost no experience with either mono or linux application development. Can someone help me how to diagnose what's happening here and how to fix it?
 Thanks in advance

```
protected void ChangeFolder (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dirInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo (filechooserbutton1.Uri.ToString ()); 
    var files = dirInfo.GetFiles ();
    // do something with files variable

}
```

Value of `filechooserbutton1.Uri.ToString ()` is "file:///home/username/music" (that's folder i have selected)...

Comment: what's the value of `filechooserbutton1.Uri.ToString()` ?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you examined the dirInfo object after its construction? What state is filechooserbutton1 in? Does it have a valid value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(filechooserbutton1.FullName.ToString ())` instead `Uri.ToString()`

Comment: I was looking for this on google, but how difficult is to find information for GTK#!!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is only ONE exception that GetFiles can throw: DirectoryNotFoundException
So, your path, defined by 'filechooserbutton1.Uri.ToString ()' is invalid.

Check it's value with a breakpoint in the second line and try to use a "hardcoded" path that you are sure it exists.

**EDIT**

Remember that paths in Linux require "/" as the separator.

**EDIT**

"file:///..." is not a valid path.

**EDIT**

To catch exceptions, use the famous "try{ } catch(Exception ex) { //show message here }

Comment: i don't get any exception... application just exits on 2nd line...
file:/// is response from FileChoserButton...

Comment: @user972940, see my answer (last edit). You can use a try/catch block to catch exceptions. A simple program trying to use your path (I have it, just changed to my user), gives me a "Directory not found" exception.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i got that too.. But how to get valid file path from filechosebutton widget?
As i said, i have almost no experience with both linux and mono...

Comment: I do not know this widget. What is its Type? Anyway, probably you will not want to use the "URI" option. Maybe another one... But I need to know which widget is this to tell you.

Comment: Hum... @user972940, are you using GTK#?